# Outputting integers from an ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I made an ArrayList< ArrayList< Integer >> to hold the coordinates of a chessboard.  I am having trouble simply outputting the numbers. When I output the sizes of the ArrayLists, it tells me safeSquares has 64 objects after the first set of for loops, but that innerList always has the size of zero after the "for(ArrayList innerList : safeSquares)" line.  It seems as though safeSquares never passes the arrayLists to innerList, but tries to 64 times.

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> safeSquares = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
static ArrayList<Integer> squares = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  squares.add(i);
  for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
    squares.add(x);
    safeSquares.add(squares);
    squares.remove(1);
  }
  squares.clear();
}

for(ArrayList<Integer> innerList : safeSquares) {
  for (Integer number : innerList) {
    System.out.println(number + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you use squares.remove and squares.clear ?

Comment: You aren't adding 64 to squares you are adding 72 because you are adding both inside and outside the inner loop.

Then you are repeatedly removing the second item in squares each time (arrays are zero-indexed) you add the squares array.  I'm not clear what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try walking through your code one line at a time, and writing the state of squares and safeSquares after each line of code.  I think you will find that you are not accomplishing what you expect!

Then try this code, I'm not sure its exactly what you want, but I think its closer...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> safeSquares = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> squares = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> pair = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        pair.add(x);
        pair.add(i);
        squares.add(pair);
        }
    safeSquares.add(squares);
}

for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outlist : safeSquares) {
    for (ArrayList<Integer> inlist : outlist) {
        System.out.print(inlist);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[0, 0][1, 0][2, 0][3, 0][4, 0][5, 0][6, 0][7, 0]
[0, 1][1, 1][2, 1][3, 1][4, 1][5, 1][6, 1][7, 1]
[0, 2][1, 2][2, 2][3, 2][4, 2][5, 2][6, 2][7, 2]
[0, 3][1, 3][2, 3][3, 3][4, 3][5, 3][6, 3][7, 3]
[0, 4][1, 4][2, 4][3, 4][4, 4][5, 4][6, 4][7, 4]
[0, 5][1, 5][2, 5][3, 5][4, 5][5, 5][6, 5][7, 5]
[0, 6][1, 6][2, 6][3, 6][4, 6][5, 6][6, 6][7, 6]
[0, 7][1, 7][2, 7][3, 7][4, 7][5, 7][6, 7][7, 7]
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information.  I am looking to have the following pattern in safeSquares: {{0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},.......,{7,7}};  Each array inside of safeSquares would be a coordinate on the chessboard.  That's why i would remove one element each time during the inner loop and clear "squares" after each row was completed.

Comment: So, "squares" would always be a 2 element array that was added to "safeSquares."  I output the individual integers of "sqaures" and verified the integers, but I believe my problem is associated with the output of the elements within an ArrayList that is within an ArrayList. The line, for(ArrayList<Integer> innerList : safeSquares), does not pass an arrayList to "innerList."

Comment: To do that it would be best to use an Arraylist<Arraylist<Arraylist<integer>>>.  You can accomplish this with basically the same nested loops.  I'll edit my answer!

Comment: You code is actually not all that far from what you where trying for.  You could move your squares.add(i) into the inner loop after the squares.add(x) call. don't remove anything from squares, just keep adding x then i at each iteration of the inner loop.  You should however not use squares.clear, just new the Arraylist<Integer> at the top of each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for gnate, thank you.  I'm new to Java, so it was hard to explain exactly what was going on or what I intended to find.

Comment: no problem!  draw pictures, it will help you, but i realize they are hard to post here.

Answer (score 0):

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> safeSquares = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
static ArrayList<Integer> squares; 

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    squares = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
       squares.add(x);
 }
 safeSquares.add(squares);
}

for(ArrayList<Integer> innerList : safeSquares) {
    for (Integer number : innerList) {
    System.out.println(number + " ");
    }
}
```

This would work. I believe. If you have any problems understanding what you had wrong after seeing this please do ask. I would advise you to use bi-dimensional arrays though. Such as: Array [][] int and index it with (x,y) coordinates.